# Slow upload with paperclip

Tags: performance, upload, paperclip

Hi i have bought a vps. 
i've installed ree 1.8.7 + passenger with apache, paperclip and imagemagick.

I have i site with a form for file upload.

When i try to submit this form the operation takes much time (like 1-2 minutes).

What can be the cause?

In localhost and in my old hosting it works well.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be that your connection to your VPS is bad.

You can do two things.

1. Ping your webserver.
2. Download a decent sized file to test the transfer speeds.